# Python kill batch file process failed

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess

I'm attempting to use Python `subprocess.Popen` to run a batch file, which executes ***xfoil.exe*** and feeds it some parameters. Then it waits until xfoil.exe exits.

I've used the following code as a batch runner, which waits for the process to exit with a timeout. The process is killed if it times out.

```
def Bat_Runner(args, **kwargs):
    """
    Batch runner
    :param args:
    :return:
    """
    si = STARTUPINFO()
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    process = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
    try:
        process.wait(kwargs['timeout'])
    except KeyError:
        process.wait()
    except TimeoutExpired:
        process.kill()
        raise TimeoutError
```

However, sometimes ***xfoil.exe*** fails and hangs, in which case the batch file also hangs, and the main program gets stuck at `process.wait(kwargs['timeout])`. Even when the time limit is reached, the batch process is not killed. In this case, if I manually run the batch file by double clicking "XXX.bat", the console window also hangs.

What is the reason of this? I'm a bit puzzled regarding this since the `Bat_Runner` function has been tested and works well at killing the process in some cases, but not this case.

Also, if `kill()` is killing the batch process, is there any way to kill the ***xfoil.exe*** process that it invokes?

========================= Update Line ===============================

PS:

1 This *Bat_Runner* function will be called by this code:

```
def _solve_by_Xfoil(self, alpha_set, Mach_number, Raynolds_number, parameter, is_viscus=True, **kwargs):
    ...many unrelated codes...
    try:
        if kwargs.get('timeout'):
            Bat_Runner(batch_file__bat, timout=kwargs['timeout'])
        else:
            Bat_Runner(batch_file__bat, timeout=5)
    except TimeoutError:
        print(''.join((Print_Colors.FAIL, 'Warning!\n', Print_Colors.ENDC,
               'Current Airfoil {} Cannot get an Output: {}!')).format(self._name, parameter))
```

The codes are relatively big so for simplisity I just show what matters.Theoritically it will print an fail information. The *_solve_by_Xfoil* will be called by following:

```
cl_str_list = self._solve_by_Xfoil(alpha_range, Mach_number, Raynolds_number, 'CL', is_viscus=is_viscus,timeout=10, **kwargs)
```

The batch_file__bat(same as XXX.bat) is a file contain follows:

> xfoil.exe < xfoil_batch_pid_11028.dat

2 For referrence the ***xfoil.exe*** is the this [opensource program](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/), I'm using its excutable exe file in this case, it will show a console window, just type some instructions to make it run, so I'm using batch file to run it.

3 Double click the batch file ***XXX.bat*** when ***xfoil.exe*** fails and hangs, the cmd window will stay and show following:
[image]
the batch file will run and disappear automatically if ***xfoil.exe*** run successfuly.

4 I'm prety sure that the batch file did not been killed because when I mannualy delete the *xfoil_batch_pid_11028.dat* which feeds to ***xfoil.exe*** when it fails, a message show that operation could not been completed cause this file has been open by windos cmd.

Comment: The only reason I'd see is that the `process.wait`call is not raising the  `TimeoutExpired` exception. Not knowing what "xfoil.exe" does is pretty difficult, however there is a worthy note in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait): "This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE ". Can you try without declaring the subprocess with "stdout=PIPE"?

Comment: Please provide the exact call so people can see the `timeout` value you're using. If the wait really has a timeout, then it should kill the CMD process that runs the batch file. As is, it *will not* kill the xfoil.exe process.

Comment: @asettouf Thanks for your suggestions though I've tried that but there's no difference

Comment: @eryksun I've updated this question. I'm certainly sure that this timeout command will work in some cases, I've tested this code for a while and it will kill the batch most time when xfoil.exe run more than timelimit. However,  I may guess that there's a certain circumstance that xfoil.exe will stuck and the cmd cannot be killed as usual.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not manage yet to reproduce the problem on my end, but could you try the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/4121573)?

Comment: If `xfoil.exe < xfoil_batch_pid_11028.dat` is the only line in the batch script, you should simplify your problem by running xfoil.exe directly via subprocess. You can open the .dat file for reading and pass it to `Popen` as `stdin`.

Comment: If you kill the CMD instance that's running the batch script, there's very little chance that it doesn't work. It calls `TerminateProcess`, which has the kernel abruptly kill a process, in which case there shouldn't be a problem with the .dat file still being open by cmd.exe. But you won't be able to delete it because xfoil.exe has a handle for it as its `StandardInput`. Also, the console remaining open doesn't mean cmd.exe is still running. The console window is separately hosted by conhost.exe. cmd.exe is a console client the same as python.exe, powershell.exe, or xfoil.exe.

Comment: Also, `Bat_Runner` doesn't use `stdin` or `stderr`, so it should set them to `DEVNULL` as well. This is more reliable when running in Windows 7 and earlier with a non-console Python process such as pythonw.exe. Otherwise `Popen` may fail if it tries to duplicate a standard handle from the current process that's invalid. This occurs on older versions of Windows, which inherit the standard handle values for a non-console process even though they're not valid, inherited handles in the child process. Also, using the `NUL` device is simpler, since its read and write operations never block.

Comment: @eryksun Many thanks for the detailed explanation, I've get little experience with subprocess. I'll turn to use subprocess to derectly call xfoil.exe instead. But I still get two questions: 1. if a console remaining while the cmd has finished running, how could I close that since it dosen't return a end run signal. 2.how could I kill xfoil.exe directly in batch file run cases?

Comment: The console remains open because xfoil is still attached to it. It will close as soon as xfoil either exits (or is forcibly terminated) or detaches by calling `FreeConsole`. The latter isn't a factor in your case, so focus on killing xfoil. If you're attached to the same console, one option is to run the batch script with `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`. Then you can use `process.send_signal(signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)`, which will send a Ctrl+Break to just that process group (i.e. CMD and xfoil), and this should kill xfoil. Then use `process.kill()` to kill CMD.

Comment: @eryksun I've attempting to use popen to directly run xfoil.exe and use stdin to send commands to it. But now I wonder how to make sure that xfoil.exe could receive next piece of commands every time it has just finished running last command? I cannot get any output if just use stdin.write() to loop instructions unless setting a time.sleep() to wait for a while, is there any advice? Thanks.